# Is there a way to pass information to a Google Form from a link sent in an email (parameters in the URL maybe)?

Tags: google-apps-script

I want to send an email to folks using a script that will ask them to confirm an appointment. I'd like to make it easy for them to confirm. I was thinking I could have a link go to a Google Form, but I would like that form to contain information about the appointment; I thought about putting parameters in the form URL (e.g. [https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/[formID]/viewform?location=Office1&subject=management](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/%5BformID%5D/viewform?location=Office1&subject=management)) but I don't see a way to grab that URL in the script attached to the form (only the normal URL of the form). Any way I can get the URL with the parameters? Or is there some other way to pass information to the form? (Or, failing that, to a Google Doc or something?)

I tried using getPublishedURL but that gets the standard URL, no parameters...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add the Edit Response URL of a Google Form to its spreadsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57936050/add-the-edit-response-url-of-a-google-form-to-its-spreadsheet)

Comment: Hi and welcome. `getEditResponseUrl` is easily created and can be included in an email. Having said that, I respectfully suggest that Google Forms is a poor choice for this scenario, and that your question shows little thought about EXACTLY what a user can/will do when directed to that URL. They might wish to respond in several ways such as 1) confirm the appointment, 2) modify the appointment, 3) cancel the appointment. How do you propose to handle these responses? In any event, such matters are not in the scope of this question.

Comment: Well, to clarify: this is for my STAFF to confirm they are aware of an appointment that has been assigned to them. All I want is a line that says "Monday 2/5 at 3 PM" and a submit button. So I want to be able to pass that information in to the form somehow. I don't think getEditResponseUrl does that, does it? It would just give me the URL to edit form responses, not the URL the form was submitted from?

Answer (score 0):

Question: Is a way to pass parameter information to a Google Form from a link sent in an email.

Answer: No.

But there is a way that you can use a Google Forms link, sent in an email, that would enable a person to confirm an appointment.

---

In brief:

- create a Google Form with three questions

  - Question 1 = Title: "User Details", Type: "Paragraph Text"
  - Question 2 = Title: "My appoitment time is", Type: "Short-answer Text"
  - Question 3 = Title: "Acknowledgement", Type: "List Item", one options = "yes"
- create a Google spreadsheet with two sheets
- sheet 1 = user details = name, email, appointment time plus two checkboxes ("ResponseCreated" and "Email sent")
- sheet 2 = Form Responses - linked from the Google Form

  - add one additional column: "EditResponse URL"
- write/run a script to create form responses using the data on sheet1
- this will populate questions 1 and 2
- Sheet 2(Form Responses) is automatically updated.
- write/run a script to create the `EditResponseUrl` for the data on sheet="Form Responses"
- write/run a script to send emails to the user details on Sheet1

  - use the `EditResponseUrl` from sheet 2 to create an HTML link in the email

-when each user clicks the link in their email, they are directed to a form that contains **their** details, and the time of **their** appointment.

- They select "Yes" (to acknowledge the appointyment) and then Submit.
- Sheet 2 is automatically updated from the form - this is your evidence of their acknowledgement.

---

**Create Form Responses**

```
function createResponse() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var sourceSheetName = "User details"
  var source = ss.getSheetByName(sourceSheetName)

  // get the number of entries
  var aVals = source.getRange("A2:A").getValues()
  var aLast = aVals.filter(String).length
  // get the data; 3 columns plus a checkbox// one row = header
  var sourceRange = source.getRange(2,1,aLast,4)
  //Logger.log("DEBUG: source range = "+sourceRange.getA1Notation())
  var sourceValues = sourceRange.getValues()

  var formUrl = ss.getFormUrl();
  var form = FormApp.openByUrl(formUrl); // grabs the connected form
  var questions = form.getItems();
  // Getting the fields of the form questions 
  var userInfo = questions[0].asParagraphTextItem();
  var appntInfo = questions[1].asTextItem();

  var updateArray = new Array

  for(i = 0; i < sourceValues.length; i++) {
    if (sourceValues[i][3] == false){
      var formResponse = form.createResponse();
      var d1 = "Name: "+sourceValues[i][0]+"\nEmail address: "+sourceValues[i][1]
      var r1 = userInfo.createResponse(d1)
      var d2 = sourceValues[i][2]
      var r2 = appntInfo.createResponse(d2)
     
      formResponse.withItemResponse(r1)
      formResponse.withItemResponse(r2)
      formResponse.submit()
      updateArray.push([true])
    }
    else {
      updateArray.push([true])
    }
  }
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: checkbox range = "+source.getRange(2,4,sourceValues.length).getA1Notation())
  // Logger.log(updateArray) // DEBUG
  source.getRange(2,4,sourceValues.length).setValues(updateArray)
}
```

---

**Get EditResponseUrl**

```
function responseURL() {
  var form = FormApp.openById('10cG91VSwmIvCS8PQbJwtrQk47uWVmcH6i5pX83KsuVE')
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Form Responses 1')
  var formResponses = form.getResponses()
  
  for (var i = 0; i < formResponses.length; i++) {
    var formResponse = formResponses[i]
    sheet.getRange(i+2, 5).setValue(formResponse.getEditResponseUrl());
  }
}
```

---

**Send email**

```
function sendEmails(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var userSheetName = "User details"
  var usersheet = ss.getSheetByName(userSheetName)
  var formSheetName = "Form Responses 1"
  var formsheet = ss.getSheetByName(formSheetName)

  // get the number of entries
  var aVals = usersheet.getRange("A2:A").getValues()
  var aLast = aVals.filter(String).length
  // get the data; 3 columns// one row = header
  var userRange = usersheet.getRange(2,1,aLast,5)
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: source range = "+userRange.getA1Notation())
  var userValues = userRange.getValues()
  var formRange = formsheet.getRange(2,1,aLast,5)
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: form range = "+formRange.getA1Notation())
  var formValues = formRange.getValues()
 //Logger.log(formValues)
  // return
  var sentArray = new Array
  var emailSubject = "Request for Confirmation of Appointment"

  for (var i=0;i<userValues.length;i++){
    if (userValues[i][4] == false){ // test if email has already been sent
      var name = userValues[i][0]
      var email = userValues[i][1]
      var apptTime = userValues[i][2]
      var respURL = formValues[i][4]

      var html_link = "<a href='"+respURL+"'> our Appointment confirmation form</a>"
      //Logger.log(html_link)

      var html_body = "Hello, "+ name +",<br><br>" 
                 + "Your appointment is at "+apptTime+". Would you please confirm your appointment by going to " + html_link + ".<br><br>"
                 + "Thank you, <br>"
                 + "Signature"    
      MailApp.sendEmail({
        to: email,
        subject: emailSubject,
        body: "Can add a Plain Text version of the email body here for email apps that dont do html",
        htmlBody: html_body
      })
      sentArray.push([true])
      Logger.log("mail sent to "+name)
    }
    else{
      sentArray.push([true])
    }
  }
  usersheet.getRange(2,5,userValues.length).setValues(sentArray)
}
```

---

**User Details (sheet1)**

[image: user details]

---

**Form Responses (sheet2)**

[image: form responses]

---

**Email**

[image: email]

---

**Form - Confirm appointment**

[image: form]